# fs.writeFile not updating when multiple users use the command

Tags: discord, discord.js

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    if (!defFile[cduser].cd) {
    
    } else {
      let var1 = defFile[mentionId].autodefensa; 
      let var3 = defFile[mentionId].bomba;
      defFile[mentionId] = {
        autodefensa: var1,
        defensaext: 0,
        bomba: var3
      }
      message.channel.send('Message here')
      fs.writeFile ("./defensa.json", JSON.stringify(defFile, null, 4), err => {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
    } message.author.send(cdyou2)
}, 30000)
```

What is meant to do is that, whenever a user inputs the command, in gives a boost and after a short time it goes. mentionId works fine, however fs.writeFile only updates the last user and not the ones who where before. This only happens when more than 1 person inputs the command before the timer goes, tho. Any solution for this?